# Using mail form in rails for contact: Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, email

Before you ask, I am connected to the internet. I have tried using the form on my herokuapp and the form on my localhost and neither work. They should be sending to my email. Also I tried using it with the console...

`c = Contact.new(:name => 'Jose', :email => 'bob@bob.com', :message => 'blah')`
`c.deliver`

This is where I get this...

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `initialize'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:540:in `tcp_socket'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `block in do_start'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in `timeout'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:549:in `do_start'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:456:in `block in deliver_mail'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:454:in `deliver_mail'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `deliver'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mail_form-1.5.0/lib/mail_form/delivery.rb:151:in `deliver!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run__1162424905731419627__deliver__callbacks'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mail_form-1.5.0/lib/mail_form/shim.rb:49:in `deliver'
    from (irb):2
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'irb(main):003:0>
```

My code in Contact.rb

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "Someone contacted you on your website!",
      :to => "myemail@gmail.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

My contact form in haml

```
.row
  .large-8.small-centered.columns
    %div{align: "center"}
      %h2 Send A message to Us
      = form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
        .row
          .large-12.columns
            %h2 Name
            = f.text_field :name, :required => true, :placeholder => 'John Smith'
        .row
          .large-12.columns
            %h2 Email
            = f.text_field :email, :required => true, :placeholder => 'You@example.com'
        .row
          .large-12.columns
            %h2 Message
            = f.text_area :message, :as => :text, :required => true, :size => "30x10" 
        .hidden
          = f.text_field :nickname, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!'
        %div
          = f.submit 'Send message'
```

The gym is installed as well

```
gem 'mail_form'
gem 'simple_form'
```

routes.rb

```
  match '/contacts', to: 'contacts#new', via: 'get'
  resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]
```

contacts controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Thank you for contacting me. I will reply shortly!")
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

My Development Configuration(for localhost)

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }


  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

My Production(For Heroku)

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

I really don't know why it is doing this and the other explanations of this error on here do not work for me.

Comment: Do you have mailer configuration?

Comment: Found change `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp` to `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail` but really same as to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: Didn't think of adding that configuration. I will place that in there.

Comment: changing to sendmail didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue. Stupid me forgot to add the gmail mailer. I didn't realize I needed it with mail form. The tutorial I used never put in that type of information.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'gmail.com',
  user_name:            'myname@gmail.com',
  password:             'mypassword',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Answer (score 2):

do rake db:migrate
i spent one hour on it and had this issue Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)

and then when i put rake db:migrate and restart the server again it worked

Answer (score 1):

I'm not allowed to reply directly to nour's solution above (or upvote it), but running rails db:migrate was an unexpected help for me.

I was having email problems with a Rails app running on Heroku (email thru Sendgrid) since a recent upgrade to Rails 7.0

Somehow, even though there were no pending migrations in my app, the "`Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:25)`" error message disappeared and emails began working again.